# Java API for Kafka SQL

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a Kafka Topic and I want to Get the last 5 minutes of data.

I Know that I can do that with Kafka SQL

```
CREATE STREAM test_stream ( name varchar, age int ) WITH (kafka_topic='my_topic', value_format='JSON')
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM test_stream WHERE ROWTIME <= 1563356280000;
```

I want to do the same for a Web Service Java, and I can't find the good libraries, have anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: You can use [Streams DSL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-dsl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to do the same for a Web Service Java, and I can't find the good libraries, have anyone faced this issue ?

You can use the [KSQL REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/api.html).

If, however, you want to write your stream processing code natively in Java, you should take a look at [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/).